# Deleting large numbers of files in python

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to remove all files found in a directory.  The accepted answer to [Delete Folder Contents in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185936/delete-folder-contents-in-python) suggests getting a list of all files and calling "unlink" on them in a loop.

Suppose I have thousands of files on a network share, and want to tie up the directory for as short a time as possible.

Is it more efficient to delete them all using a shell command like `rm -f /path/*` or by using `shutils.rmtree` or some such?

Comment: If you move the directory to a new name (deleteme is good) then mkdir a new one, you can delete the old one in the background at your leisure.

Comment: interesting @nmichaels.  What about simply moving it to /dev/null ?

Comment: That won't be any faster than deleting; moving with `os.rename` on the same filesystem is super fast.

Comment: @Dave: Interesting idea, but `mv: cannot overwrite non-directory `/dev/null' with directory `deleteme/'`

Comment: If you can use Python 3.5, using os.scandir() in place of os.listdir() should be substantially faster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you actually want to delete the whole directory tree, `shutils.rmtree` should be faster than `os.remove` (which is the same as `os.unlink`). It also allows you to specify a callback function to handle errors.

The suggestion in the comment by @nmichaels is also good, you can `os.rename` the directory then make a new one in its place and use `shutils.rmtree` on the original, renamed directory.

Comment: The question is about comparing python (rmtree is the best i think) to unix shell (rm -Rf <tree>).

Comment: @orzel That's what he said, but I thought what he really meant was how to do it quickly, which `rmtree` does. He accepted my answer so we have to assume I addressed his intent.

Comment: Might be. I am interested in the original question : which one is faster, python/rmtree or forking a 'rm -Rf' ? I was looking for tests/figures and arguments about this.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this solution and it seems to work well:

```
while os.path.exists(file_to_delete):
  os.remove(file_to_delete)
```