# Deleting files in folder with python

Tags: python

I have one folder with one geodatabase and two other files (txt). I used zip and zipped them. So now in this folder i have gdb, txt,txt, and new zip file. Now I need to delete those files that were zipped, so that will be only zip file in the folder. 
I wrote the following code:

```
def remove_files():
   for l in os.listdir(DestPath):
      if l.find('zipped.zip') > -1:
         pass
      else:
           print ('Deleting ' + l)
           os.remove(l)
```

But got:

```
Error Info: 
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'geogeo.gdb'
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of that `l.find('zipped.zip') > -1` you can simply use `'zipped.zip' in l`

Answer (score 7):

`os.listdir` only returns filenames, not complete paths.
`os.remove` uses the current working directory if only a filename is given. If the current working directory is different than `DestPath`, then you need to supply the full path:

```
os.remove(os.path.join(DestPath,l))
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker: True; it will remove anything without `zipped.zip` anywhere in its filename.

Comment: Ah, I thought your solution was supposed to replace the entire code snippet by Z77, not just the `os.remove()` line. My bad.

Comment: Now I got another error: Error Info: 
[Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:/path\\geogeo.gdb'

Comment: There is a problem because gdb is considered is subfolder? Because I can delete all other files in main folder, just not gdb.

Comment: def remove_files():
   for l in os.listdir(DestPath):
      if 'zipped.zip' in l:
         pass
      elif '.gdb.' in l:
              rmtree(os.path.join(DestPath,l))
      else:
           print ('Deleting ' + l)
           os.remove(os.path.join(DestPath,l))

I tried this delete also file.gdb as a folder..But still have problem with [error 5] Acesss is denied. I really do not know what to do :(((

Comment: Solution to my problem is http://stackoverflow.com/a/6615332/334172  Latest post!