# Script delete C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6\namespace

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to create a Python script to Delete everying under `C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6\namespace`
I need an Idea.. to do it in the command line i have to go to cmd an then `psexec -s cmd` than i have to goto  `C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6\namespace` and than rd *what ever folder there.. i want to create a script to remove all.. any help

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

This code should delete any files or directories in your directory:

```
import os, shutil
folder = "C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6\namespace"
for item in os.listdir(folder):
    path = os.path.join(folder, item)
    try:
        os.unlink(path) # delete if the item is a file
    except Exception as e:
        shutil.rmtree(path) # delete if the item is a folder
```

This has been [answered previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185936/delete-folder-contents-in-python).

Comment: My understanding of his question "what ever folder there ... to remove all" sounds like he's looking for something recursive.

Comment: Good point, I've added code to remove folders as well as files.

Comment: Nice, you sir get an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

A [simple Google search](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) and a few modifications:

```
import os
mainPath = "C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6\namespace"
files = os.listdir(mainPath)
for f in files:
    os.remove('{}/{}'.format(mainPath, f))
```

If you want to recursively find all of the files and THEN delete them all (this is a small script I wrote yesterday):

```
import os, os.path
def getAllFiles(mainPath):
    subPaths = os.listdir(mainPath)
    for path in subPaths:
        pathDir = '{}\{}'.format(mainPath, path)
        if os.path.isdir(pathDir):
            paths.extend(getAllFiles(pathDir, paths))
        else:
                paths.append(pathDir)
    return paths
```

So then you can do:

```
files = getAllFiles(mainPath)
for f in files:
    os.remove(f)
```

Note: the recursive algorithm gets somewhat slow (and may raise a `MemoryError`) if there are too many subfolders (it creates a lot of recursive nodes).

To avoid this, you can use the recursive function as a helper function, which is called by a main iterative function:

```
def getDirs(path):
    sub = os.listdir(path)
    paths = []
    for p in sub:
        pDir = '{}\{}'.format(path, p)
        if os.path.isdir(pDir):
            paths.extend(getAllFiles(pDir, paths)) # getAllFiles is the same as above
        else:
            paths.append(pDir)
    return paths
```

It get's slow for very large subfolders, however. Going through `C:\Python27\Lib` takes about 6-7 seconds for me (it has about 5k+ files in it, and many, many subfolders).