# Permission denied doing os.mkdir(d) after running shutil.rmtree(d) in Python

Tags: python, io, shutil

Very often in the Windows 7 console if I run a python program twice very quickly that does

```
if os.path.isdir(d):
    shutil.rmtree(d)
if not os.path.exists(d):
    os.mkdir(d)
```

where `d` is the name of a directory with many files, I get a "Permission denied" for the `mkdir` command. But if I run once, then wait some seconds, then run again I do not get such error. 
What is the problem here?

Comment: FYI some related discussion thread here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/sVnSa5iWWzg

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three things that come to mind:

1. Windows itself delays some file operations in order to preserve metadata. If you for example rename a file and create another one in its location, Windows has a time-window where things like ACLs are transferred to the new file. This is a "feature" to preserve this metadata even for programs that write a new file before deleting the old one, in order to not loose data when something fails in the middle.
2. Malware scanners sometimes hook into filesystem operations and perform a scan on files, searching for malware (or government-critic texts, if you're paranoid, and maybe even if you're not paranoid). During that scan, some other accesses to the file are blocked.
3. Lastly, I'm not sure how `shutil.rmtree()` is implemented, but under Windows, some tree operations are actually implemented not by the OS core but by the shell (i.e. Explorer) and they could be executed asynchronously, which would explain a short time window in which the path is still blocked even though the call already returned.

I believe that e.g. Subversion or rather the Apache Portable Runtime stumbled across the same problem and worked around it by simply retrying with a delay. This solution doesn't win a beauty contest, but it seems to Do The Job(tm).

Comment: Definitely, it seems that using a delay and then retry is the only solution. Thanks

Comment: There is easier solution. Just "os.rename" folder before deleting. Renaming is immediate.

Comment: Definitely not (2), since this behavior is perfectly reproducible. To me (3) sounds like the most plausible explanation. File operations being async makes me reconsider using shutil altogether.

Comment: @user443854 - another possible explanation is mentioned under the discussion section in Eryk Sun's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60181105/8425408. Basically, under Windows "delete" marks a file for deletion, but does not unlink it, until the last file handle is closed.