# Is there a python equivalent of "rm -rf"?

Tags: python

I want to delete a folder if is already present,Any inputs on how to delete a dir if it exists?Is there a python equivalent of "rm -rf" ?

if os.path.isdir('./.repo'):
    shutil.rmtree('./.repo')

Comment: This perhaps: http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree, or this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/185936/65387

Comment: Sure, just have Python execute the shell command. You can use `os.system("rm -rf")`, or you can use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: @jdero Vote to close.

Comment: @2rs2ts That's not OS-independent

Comment: -1: Google your *exact* question title and click on any of the first 100 links.

Comment: @Mark Of course! But that is the equivalent of `rm -rf`. Not the equivalent of recursively removing all subdirectories and their contents.

Comment: @Mark, neither is "rm -rf" :)

Comment: @JackLeow: Sure, if you take "equivalent" to mean he enjoys the OS-dependency ;)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [shutil.rmtree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree)

> shutil.rmtree(path[, ignore_errors[, onerror]])
>
> Delete an entire
> directory tree; path must point to a directory (but not a symbolic
> link to a directory). If ignore_errors is true, errors resulting from
> failed removals will be ignored; if false or omitted, such errors are
> handled by calling a handler specified by onerror or, if that is
> omitted, they raise an exception.
>
> If onerror is provided, it must be a callable that accepts three
> parameters: function, path, and excinfo. The first parameter,
> function, is the function which raised the exception; it will be
> os.path.islink(), os.listdir(), os.remove() or os.rmdir(). The second
> parameter, path, will be the path name passed to function. The third
> parameter, excinfo, will be the exception information return by
> sys.exc_info(). Exceptions raised by onerror will not be caught.
>
> Changed in version 2.6: Explicitly check for path being a symbolic
> link and raise OSError in that case.

**Note:** rm -fr path is not strictly equivalent to shutil.rmtree("path", ignore_errors = True). rm -fr will remove readonly files, rmtree will not. (see @Richard's comment below)

Comment: I post it's a dupe before you post this, yet you get 60 points and I get a helpful flag... Interesting point system here :P, considering this is a near-direct copy of the selected answer of my linked thread.

Comment: @jdero: There's only one simple answer to this question, so I'm not sure how else it should look.

Comment: Ouch, I save the downvotes for answers that are very wrong. For the record, I didn't click through to the dupe until after I posted this. besides link only answers are discouraged nowdays.

Comment: Note: rm -fr _path_  is not strictly equivalent to shutil.rmtree("_path_", ignore_errors = True).  rm -fr will remove readonly files, rmtree will not.  I found this on windows 10 python 2.7.15

Comment: Thanks Richard. I've added your note to my answer