# Django delete files from a directory not working

Tags: python, django

The following is my file deletion code:

```
path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
os.remove(os.path.join(path, file_name))
```

When run I get the following HTTP 500 error:

> WindowsError at /project/delete_files/
>
> [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: u'C:\DjangoEmt/static/uploads/bridge.jpg'

I have checked the file exists in the directory. Can someone please help me as to why its not working.

Sidenote: I am using ajax in django if this makes any difference.

Comment: problem solved. path should not be like this i have given. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185936/delete-folder-contents-in-python

Answer (score 1):

I see in your file path error, a combination of slash and backslash.
replace '/' to '\' if your application run on windows system.

```
path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
os.remove(os.path.join(path, file_name.replace('/', '\')))
```