# python delete all files (recursively) without the folder itself

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, directory, debian-based

What's the best way to delete all files and dirs inside a folder without deleting the folder itself using python?
Using:

```
if os.path.exists("path/to/folder"):
    shutil.rmtree("path/to/folder/*")
```

Won't to the trick since the rmtree() doesn't understand UNIX style (/*). rmtree itself is fine, but it deleted the folder too, which I don't need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185936/delete-folder-contents-in-python

Answer (score -1):

You could just recreate the folder after you delete it.

```
import os
path = "/home/zach/Desktop"
filename = "django"
if os.path.exists(path):
    os.system("cd %s" %path)
    os.system("rm -rf %s" %filename)
    print("deleted file")
    os.system("mkdir %s" %filename)
    print("created file")
else:
    print("error")
```

Comment: seems mixed up *file* and *folder*. The code does not check whether the path is a file or a folder.