# How do I delete multiple files in a folder?

Tags: python, file

I wanted to ask the forum how can I delete multiple files in a folder using Python. I tried using the import os module along with `os.unlink()` module, but it doesn't work. Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Comment: Repeated use of `os.unlink` should be a suitable means of removing multiple files. If your code did not work, please post a [mcve] and a precise description of what actually happened when you ran it. If you got an error message, post that too, including stack trace.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? If you need help fixing your code, you have to post a [mcve]. Or if you _aren't_ asking for help debugging your code, then I'm afraid this is a duplicate, because "how do I delete files" has been asked innumerable times in the past.

Comment: Seems to be a similar question,Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185936/how-to-delete-the-contents-of-a-folder-in-python

Comment: import os
for filename in os.listdir('c:\\users\\user1\\Pictures'):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        os.unlink(filename)

Comment: And this is the error I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user1/Documents/My Scripts/delete2.py", line 4, in <module>
    os.unlink(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'New Text Document.txt'

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because the filename used in the os.unlink(filename) isn't a full path to the file (os.listdir() just returns a sequence of filenames). You probably need to use `os.path.join()` to prefix the `'c:\\users\\user1'` folder to it first.

Something along these lines:

```
import os

folder = 'c:\\users\\user1\\Pictures'
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        os.unlink(os.path.join(folder, filename))
```

Comment: @Datalink: I thought you said this solved your problem?