# How can I delete multiple files using a Python script?

Tags: python

I am playing around with some python scripts and I ran into a problem with the script I'm writing. It's supposed to find all the files in a folder that meets the criteria and then delete it. However, it finds the files, but at the time of deleting the file, it says that the file is not found.

This is my code:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir('C:\\New folder\\'):
    if filename.endswith(".rdp"):
        os.unlink(filename)
```

And this is the error I get after running it:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

Can somebody assist with this?

Comment: The path to the file is `'C:\\New folder\\' + filename`. You can pass that to `unlink`, not just the filename.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete the contents of a folder in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185936/how-to-delete-the-contents-of-a-folder-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.unlink`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.unlink) takes the **path** to the file, not only its `filename`. Try **pre-pending** your `filename` with the `dirname`. Like this

```
import os

dirname = 'C:\\New folder\\'

for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
    if filename.endswith(".rdp"):

        # Add your "dirname" to the file path
        os.unlink(dirname + filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively use os.walk, however it might go deeper than you want:

```
import os

for root, sub, file in os.walk("/media/"):
    if file.endswith(".rdp"):
        os.unlink(f'{root}/{file}')
```